# What to do with broken outdoor lights that left the bulbs exposed?

Tags: lighting, exterior

A hail storm has broken the outer casing of our outdoor lights, exposing the bulb.

What should I do?  Can I leave just the bulb exposed to the elements?

Answer (score 6):

Exterior light fixtures are designed so that the casing protects the electrical components inside them from the elements. Without an intact case, hail could break the bulb itself in the next storm, or rainwater could get in to short out the electric circuit.

Your options are:

- find the manufacturer's name on the light fixture, and look them up to see if you can buy replacement covers either directly from them, or they may list retailers.
- buy a new light fixture and replace the broken one. They are often so inexpensive that this might be the cheapest for you.

Comment: I would also add "hope the fixture uses a relatively standard base for its globe and see if you can get another that will fit."  Once I was on a beautifully restored 19th century train, and I noticed not only were all the globes present, they all matched.  I imagined they had spent a fortune gathering the last surviving such globes from all over the country.  They told me they were locally acquired, at K-mart.

Comment: Especially if the fixture can be replaced with an integrated-LED system, which will typically be more robust and cheaper to operate.